# Is this switch wiring normal?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch

New homeowner here and total electrical newbie.

These switches have been smelling lately, and was told this means they need replacing. No signs of any other issues in the wall, so assuming this is so.

After removing the cover I discovered this wiring to one switch, with a black and white wire going to the same connection.

Is this normal?

Thank you for your help[image]

Comment: What does that switch control?

Comment: At a basic level, black is hot, either from the circuit breaker/fuse panel, or switched.  White is neutral, or return.  So connecting a black & white together should cause the ckt brks to trip.  Note that there are exceptions to this basic wiring scheme.

Comment: @SteveSh   Neutral must be white, but white is not always neutral.

Comment: The bottom screw is connected wrong.  Assuming that white is a hot(should have black/red marked on it) the white and black should be connected with a wire nut and joined with a short wire to the screw.  Ten to one that black wire is loose on that screw and is heating up, causing the smell.  Replace that switch and wire it up right.

Comment: No it is NOT normal, also due to bad connection it will start arching and create a fire

Comment: Thanks everybody! This switch controls an out door light. Beside it is a switch that controls a chandelier. Any resources on how to wire this properly?

Comment: It's _odd_, but there's no guarantee that it's _wrong_. Pull the switch further out of the box and give us a picture showing where the black & white wires on that bottom screw go. Also, give us a picture of the wiring in that outside lite that this controls. It _might_ just be OK. If it were actually connecting a hot & neutral, it would have caused a dead short and tripped a breaker.

Comment: @crip659, _that_ (now garbage) switch has terminals designed for two wires. Somebody ignored the affordance and did that instead. I guess it's moot now, where it's so mutilated that it should be thrown in the trash. The wires from an old switch were already trained to wrap the terminals, and whoever couldn't be bothered to straighten them or strip new wire.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I see burning at the end of the hot (black) wire. It also doesn't appear to be secured very well, which might cause arcing. You could probably just seat it better.

Comment: Okay, this is great. Gonna toss the switch. So do I now get a three terminal switch?